# Closing EntityManager org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException

Tags: jpa, datanucleus, entitymanager

I have the method below:

```
public List<Profile> listProfiles(){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    List<Profile> list = null;
    try{

        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profile p");
        list = (List<Profile>)q.getResultList();

    } catch(NoResultException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR CATCHED: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally{
        em.close(); 
    }

    return list;
}
```

Accessing the return list will throw an error:
`org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed`

One trick I found is to add list.size() before closing entity manager:

```
finally{
    list.size();
    em.close(); 
}
```

Should I close entity manager? Or are there concepts I missed?

Comment: Is using `list.size()` before `em.close()` ok?

Answer (score 0):

One other "concept" is to use v2 of the GAE JPA plugin. It was released a long time ago now.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused with the phrase `Version 2.0 of the DataNucleus Plugin is an experimental` from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2

Comment: It's never been "experimental" (except in the mind of some Google doc author), since stability has been the aim from day one of its development. It passed (at release) and still passes way more tests than Googles v1 plugin does, as said countless times on this site